# Getting warning while fetching the data from excel in selenium script

Tags: java, excel, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi

While reading the data from excel using below I am getting the warnings:
I am using JDK 12.0.1

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File src = new File("FilePath");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src);
    try {
    wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
    sheet = wb.getSheet("Contacts");
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.getMessage();
    }

}
    public static String getdata(int rowNum, int colNum) throws IOException {
    cell = sheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(colNum);
    String cellData =cell.getStringCellValue();
    return cellData;

}
```

}

Warnings:
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred

WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFile$1 (file:/C:/Users/.m2/repository/org/apache/poi/poi-ooxml/3.17/poi-ooxml-3.17.jar) to field java.io.FilterInputStream.in

WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFile$1

WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations

WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release

Answer (score 1):

From the Apache POI FAQ at https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html (**emphasis added**):

> 23. Can Apache POI be compiled/used with Java 11?
>
> Including the existing binaries on Java 11 as normal jar-files should work when
>   using recent versions of Apache POI. **You may see some warnings about
>   illegal reflective access, but it should work fine despite those.** We
>   are working on getting the code changed so we avoid discouraged
>   accesses in the future.
>
> We also did some work to verify that compilation with Java 11 is
>   working and that all unit-tests pass. So Apache POI should be ready to
>   be used with current Java 11 releases.
>
> NOTE: Apache POI does not yet fully support the Java module system as
>   Apache POI is still supporting previous Java versions and the module
>   system cannot be fully supported while maintaining such support. We
>   are working on adding support for automatic modules.
>
> FYI, jaxb in current versions also causes some warnings about
>   reflective access, we cannot fix those until jaxb >= 2.4.0 is
>   available, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50251510/411846 for
>   details, you can set a system property
>   "com.sun.xml.bind.v2.bytecode.ClassTailor.noOptimize" to avoid this
>   warning.
>
> For compiling Apache POI, you should use at least version 4.1.0 when
>   it becomes available or a recent trunk checkout until then.